# Trying to learn basic CFT: Writing the torus partition function of Ising model CFT and finding the minimal model for critical limit of ising model

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I'm attempting to try and learn basic ideas in conformal field theory without reading a big yellow book, or other big books. (Edits to this question are highly sought and welcome)

**My question is the following:**

How does one construct the torus partition function of the Ising model conformal field theory in particular or just for a simple free scalar field theory that is conformally invariant, and also find the corresponding minimal model?

**Below is my convoluted idea/attempt of how to attempt this.**

0)I have managed to convince myself that I did the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation taking me from the Ising model to the "euclidean $\phi^4$" theory.  I don't know if this theory is conformally invariant. I can probably check. Technically, if it has a mass-like term it isn't. If it is not I want an excuse to kick out the problematic terms and call it free or something.

I then want to do a few weird things for the purpose of learning.

i) I feel like computing the two-point correlation function which I am thinking to be just the green function of this theory and then equating it to $\frac{1}{(|x_2 - x_1|)^{2 \Delta}}$. My goal is to extract $\Delta$ this way.

ii) I want to calculate the Casimir energy of $\phi^4$, on a cylinder.  This is supposed to be something like $E = - \frac{2 \pi(c + \bar{c})}{24}$

iii) I want to also compute c

iv) I want to use c to construct a partition function. I was going to do something silly but I have noticed that people define $H$ on a cylinder and then a partition function on a torus. I have no idea why excluding some stringy reasons. At any rate, $H$ seems to usually be defined as  $L_0 + \bar{L} - \frac{c + \bar{c}}{24}$, and then $Z[\tau] =Tr e^{2 \pi (Im \tau) H}$

iv) At this point I will have c, and we can check that  (p,q) =(4,3) minimal model is gotten hopefully? As this seems to be what the Kac table (which I am still trying to figure out) seems to say is the critical limit of the Ising model.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with CFT. However, on point $0)$, I should note that you should find a mass-like term. There are a couple subtleties. The first is that I think that the mass term is only zero at the critical point of the Ising model; it is relevant and real and should be there and cannot be waved away when one is the disordered phase. The second is that this is a mild lie and the mass term actually should be slightly negative at the transition; the interactions will renormalize the mass term, and the bare mass going to zero is not where the critical point is actually located.

Comment: Even forgetting the mass, you can't get a free field. A free field is non-interacting (i.e. no $\phi^4$ terms), but the $\phi^4$ terms are relevant in the RG sense for the Ising model/$\phi^4$ theory for $d<4$ and I believe dangerously irrelevant for larger $d$.

Comment: I think in general one is out of luck trying to find the Green's function perturbatively in the interaction strength. Maybe there are high-order perturbation theory papers out there that use fancy summation techniques and the like; I suspect that the only way to go from the Ising model to its two-point functions is via a mapping to free fermions (such as taking 2d ising to (1+1)d transverse-field Ising and then using https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02100).

Comment: Note that there's probably a lot of concepts I'm getting wrong here, and I'd be happy to discuss them more (probably in a stackexchange chat). I think the main thing you're getting wrong is that you're underestimating the difficulty of extracting information from an explicit, interacting (i.e. non-free) field theory. If you end up finding a resource that can calculate the critical exponents associated with two-point functions of the $\phi^4$ theory without using the assumptions of CFT or using the fact that there are integrable models within the same universality class, I'd be very happy

Comment: On point iii), if you want to compute c, and you're OK with numerical methods, please see problem 3.5 of the Yellow book (see my question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/671363/deducing-the-central-charge-of-the-ising-model-from-the-free-energy which has a little discussion, where I made a mistake and attempted the calculation for the antiferromagnetic model by accident)